# get the attribute value in dom4j in java

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

```
                  <Address>
                <Street>33 S 3rd st</Street><Street/><Street/><Street/>     
                 <PostalCode>95130</PostalCode>
                 <Country isoCountryCode= "US" >United 
                  States</Country>
                    </Address>
```

This is my XML.I need a country code "US".I am using XML dom4j and following its tutorial.

Here is my code snippet

```
     List<Node> list1 = e.selectNodes("//*[name() = 'Address']");
     for(Node n: list1)      
      {     
      System.out.println("CC"+n.valueOf("@isoCountryCode"));
      }
```

When i tried like above it is printing null.Can i know where i am going wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should loop out the childNodes of the adress element?

Comment: Well, what element are you selecting with selectNodes, and what element is the country code attribute actually on? You're selecting Address, but the country code is on Country. So logically you don't get a result.

Comment: Use `//Address` rather than `//*[name()='Address']`. Your code isn't wrong, it's just convoluted and slow, and will get you into bad habits when you start dealing with namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can try retrieving the attribute value for the country code using the below code.

```
List<Node> list2 = e.selectNodes("//*[name() = 'Country']");
                        for(Node n1: list2)
                        {
                            Element element2 = (Element) n1;
                            String a1 = element2.attributeValue("isoCountryCode");
                            System.out.println("CC"+a1);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
List<Node> list1 = e.selectNodes("//*[name() = 'Address']");
     for(Node n: list1)      
      {     
      System.out.println("CC"+n.selectSingleNode("Country").valueOf("@isoCountryCode"));
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution